# Dropdown Option set innerHTML sets value as well

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I just found out that in FF, if you are dynamically creating an OPTION DOM element inside a SELECT element and just set its innerHTML, it sets both the innerHTML i.e. the displayed text as well as the value of the OPTION.

var opt = document.createElement('OPTION');
 opt.innerHTML = 'Opt';

this set the *"value"* attribute as well of the element.

Is this correct behavior? I haven't been able to replicate this for IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

innerHTML is not well defined here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.innerHTML

> As there is no public specification
>   for this property, implementations
>   differ widely. For example, when text
>   is entered into a text input, IE will
>   change the value attribute of the
>   input's innerHTML property but Gecko
>   browsers do not.

you may use something like the following code for adding option elements to a select element:

```
var elOptNew = document.createElement('option');
elOptNew.text = 'Insert' + num;
elOptNew.value = 'insert' + num;
var elOptOld = elSel.options[elSel.selectedIndex];  
try {
  elSel.add(elOptNew, elOptOld); // standards compliant; doesn't work in IE
}
catch(ex) {
  elSel.add(elOptNew, elSel.selectedIndex); // IE only
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specifically set a different value for the `value` attribute, it defaults to the text in the option.

Whether it's the correct behavior or not for the `innerHTML` attribute to change the `value` attribute is not possible to say. The `innerHTML` attribute is not covered by the standards, so if there is anything that is correct behaviour it would be not to support the attribute at all.

You shold rather use the `text` attribute to set the text of the option, which is the attribute specified in the standards.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening, as far as I understand, is that if you check for the attribute value of an option

```
alert(opt.value);
```

It will return the value attribute value *if it exists*, but will return the value contained within the option tags as a fallback.  In your example, you can independently set the value attribute with

```
opt.value = "some value"
```

If you do that, the value and innerHTML values will return independent values.